# How to index the hourly, minutely futures return data

Tags: r, time-series, trading

I have some data sets which contains the hourly, minutely, and some 10secondly stock index futures return data, I was wondering how could I index them and treat them as time series objects.
I know the date() function can format the daily data, but how about the more frequent period data?

Comment: There are many different ways you can do this; the appropriate method will depend on the details of the problem you're trying to solve. I recommend you start by reading the zoo and xts vignettes.

Comment: I use the `strftime` function in base R for nearly all my character-to-Date formatting, it's worth a look